# Typesense extension finished with status: timeout

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, typesense

I created a TypeSense Cloud account and created a collection.

[image]

Then I installed the TypeSense extension.
[image]

But in TypeSense Cloud nothing is indexed.

What Should I Do?

My log is ending with timeout

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your extension configuration, under "Typesense Hosts", it looks like you've only entered the Cluster ID (which is the random string) instead of the full hostname.

You want to enter the hostname as "randomid.a1.typesense.net", instead of just "randomid".